# Any problem with creating a new Struts Action instance from the Action's execute() method?

Tags: java, struts, instance

I'm using Struts 1.1 (don't get me started), and upgrading is not an option right now.  Unfortunately, the whole singleton action approach drives me nuts and makes the action rather complicated since we can't use instance variables and the like, meaning all the necessary objects need to be passed around to all the methods as parameters.  I prefer using instance variables, so I'd like to create a new instance of the Action for each request from the Action's execute method, like this:

```
public ActionForward execute (ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return (new SaveUserDataAction()).instanceExecute(mapping, form, request, response);
}

public ActionForward instanceExecute (ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // all normal execute stuff goes here
}
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering if you folks can think of any problems with this approach.  I'm aware that this will take a few extra CPU cycles due to the extra object creation, but the wisdom these days is that there's a ton of object creation going on for each request and one more will go unnoticed; not to mention it's worth it to improve readability and maintainability.  Are there other disadvantages that are more severe?

Also, is there an easier way to do it than this semi-kludgy approach?  Perhaps a Struts-supported approach?

Comment: Struts action are not Singletons.

Comment: In Struts 1.1 they are treated like singletons, ie the same instance is used in different threads.

Answer (score 1):

[Struts 1.1 Actions](http://struts.apache.org/1.1/userGuide/introduction.html#overview) are not intended to do the business logic:

> In a Struts application, most of the business logic can be represented using JavaBeans. An Action can call the properties of a JavaBean without knowing how it actually works. This encapsulates the business logic, so that the Action can focus on error handling and where to forward control.

The problem is not that you're creating an **extra instance**, but that you're creating an extra **instance of the action** instead of some helper/dao.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am not interested in creating this new instance of the Action for business logic, but rather for the typical Action logic.  I'd like to be able to use instance variables for that, which would in turn create various objects in the business layer to perform business logic.

Comment: Still, why do you need instance variables if you're not performing business logic? Your action should be just a thin layer of glue, as data validation belongs to ValidatorForms, access control should be placed in a Filter and database manipulation should be in the model's JavaBeans. What are you doing in that Action?

Comment: I'm afraid we simply have a lot of glue!  Specifically, while we perform much validation in the form, there's some which depends on  data which is expensive to load; since it's expensive and the data will be needed later in the action (to pass into business layer methods), we load it in the action and do that bit of validation there.  Same answer for some authorization - simple authorization is done elsewhere, but others can't be done until the expensive data are loaded.  Much could be improved if we had one operation per action but sadly they're grouped and that's not going away anytime soon.

Comment: My advice is to load the expensive data at the end of form's `validate()` and check it there, if no other validations failed. If the form passes validation then data will be available further on during that request for the Action and the business logic layer. Simple authorization could be left in the Action but more complex stuff belongs to business logic.